# How to convert value to array form parameter Dynamic Url and display none and block

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist

Functional not work. Because....
Parameter Url Dynamic Example.com/station=2,1,3 Maybe 2,3 / 3,1 / 3,2
I want to know id will know value dynamic array.

Example receive parameter Url station 1,2,3
Station 1 button 1 display block and Station 1,2 display block button 1,2 else none and first in active data in button tab

```js
<script>

document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("button").style.display = "none";

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var station= getParameterByName('station');

 var res = plan.split(" ",3);
 i;
for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
 res[i] = res[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
  if (res == 3) {
  document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "block";
  }else{
 if (res == 2) {
 document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "block";
  }else{
 document.getElementById("button3").style.display = "block";
  for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        res[i].style.display = "block";
  } 
 }
  }
}
 

</script>
```

```html
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">   
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown1" id="button1">button1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown2">button2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown3">button3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: so based on the dynamic id you need to show the buttons , is that the question

Comment: yes show buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will work.. happy coding :)

```js
$(document).ready(() =>{
   // showing the buttons if params is there
   const hideShowButton = (elementHref) => {
    $(`a[href='${elementHref}']`).css("display", "block");
  }


  let url; //window.location.href // Example.com/station=2,1,3 
  url = "Example.com/station=1,3";
  let buttonsToBeShow = url.split("=")[1].split(",").map(o => parseInt(o));
  buttonsToBeShow.forEach(o => {
    switch(o){
      case 1:
        hideShowButton("#dropdown1")
       break
      case 2:
        hideShowButton("#dropdown2")
       break
      case 3:
        hideShowButton("#dropdown3")
       break
      default:
        return;
    }
  })
  
 
  
})
```

```css
li a{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs">   
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown1" id="button1">button1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown2">button2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dropdown3">button3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: thank. But it does not seem a button but it a tab bootstrap

Comment: i have updated the answer based on your comment . Please check , if its fine you can just accept it.

Comment: let url; //window.location.href // Example.com/station=2,1,3 dynamic var station= getParameterByName('station'); use unknown in jquery

Comment: i didn't understand what you askl you need to get hte station values ?